# Changing the background colour with mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, navigation

I am messing around with this [scroll menu](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scrollmenu/index.html) and I want each `li` to change to different colours instead of the same one.

```
var colorOver = '#31b8da';
var colorOut = '#1f1f1f';
```

But this changes the colour of all of them.

The html looks like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="first"><a href="#">blog <span> / 2012</span></a></li>
        <li id="second"><a href="#">me <span> / 2012</span></a></li>
        <li id="third"><a href="#">etc <span> / 2012</span></a></li>
        <li id="fourth"><a href="#">etc <span> / 2012</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I assume you just tell it an `id` ...

Hopefully I've given enough info.

Thanks for any help.

[link to the demo and download](http://www.queness.com/post/256/vertical-scroll-menu-with-jquery-tutorial)

Comment: you're correct in that you need to specify different colors for each `li`. Have you tried doing that yet? If so, what have you tried and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: why not you generate a random color each time you hover the `li`

Comment: Incidentally, for demos, I'd suggest that you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo of *your* code (unless the page you're linking to *is* your code), not someone else's that you're 'adapting.' Oh, and why not just use CSS: `#first {background-color: #0f0;} #first:hover {background-color: #f00;}` and so on..?

Answer (score 0):

you could modify your css to set the colorOver and colorOut classes for each li like:

```
.first.colorOver { background-color: #31b8da; } 
.first.colorOut { background-color: #1f1f1f; }
```

and use Francois Wahl's toggleClass option:

```
 $("#sidebar ul#menu li").on("hover", function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("colorOver", "colorOut");
 });
```

then you can set colors for each li easily.